# Check hostname has CAA record in php 5.6

Tags: php, dns, lets-encrypt, caa, dns-get-record

Good morning,

I'm currently facing a small problem. To create some automated process, I need to be able to check If a hostname has a CAA record.

CAA record are needed by letsencrypt to generate certificate. I wanted to use dns_get_record to check my DNS, but unfortunately for me, we are using PHP 5.6 and dns_get_record in php 5.6 does not fetch those record.

So I was wondering if anyone had any idea in php, on how I could check if an hostname has a CAA record.

Thanks in adavance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, PHP doesn't provide any other tools for this. You'll have to settle with one of the following:

- Upgrade PHP (just do it, you'll have to anyway and it's not as painful as you may think)
- Find a user-space DNS-resolver library that works on PHP 5.6 (there are some, but I don't know of any with CAA support)
- Use something like `exec('dig caa <domainNameHere>')` to hack around it
- Do this outside of PHP

Comment: In the end I could not find something so I used dig like this          
exec('dig ' . $host . ' type257 +noall +answer', $output);